# An external developer tried to change Data storage location, but its not creating the ticket

Tags: huawei-developers, appgallery-connect

An external developer encountered a problem during changing data storage location on AGC Console. Ticket is not generating.

Answer (score 0):

Developer  is following correct way for changing data storage location.But, from second image, developer needs to click on New or message box icon.
From there, you  will be able to submit tickets for changing data storage location.

For more details please follow below reference link:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/app/agc-data-storage-location#h2-1592967796990

[image]